# Accepting attachments on a waterfall dialog and storing them locally in bot framework v4

Tags: c#, botframework, attachment, chatbot, sample

I was trying to add a functionality to take input-attachments from the user, basically trying to merge the [handling-attachments](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments) bot sample from bot framework and my custom waterfall dialog .

But how do you access iturncontext functions in the waterfall dialog? . Below is a explanation of my code.

One of my waterfall step :

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DescStepAsync2(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{


    stepContext.Values["Title"] = (string)stepContext.Result;
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("upload a image"), cancellationToken);

    var activity = stepContext.Context.Activity;
    if (activity.Attachments != null && activity.Attachments.Any())
    {

        Activity reply = (Activity)HandleIncomingAttachment(stepContext.Context.Activity);
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = reply }, cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        var reply = MessageFactory.Text("else image condition thrown");
        //  reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard().ToAttachment());
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = reply }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Here is the HandleIncomingAttachment function which i borrowed from bot builder samples linked above .

```
private static IMessageActivity HandleIncomingAttachment(IMessageActivity activity)
{
    string replyText = string.Empty;
    foreach (var file in activity.Attachments)
    {
        // Determine where the file is hosted.
        var remoteFileUrl = file.ContentUrl;

        // Save the attachment to the system temp directory.
        var localFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), file.Name);

        // Download the actual attachment
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, localFileName);
        }

        replyText += $"Attachment \"{file.Name}\"" +
                     $" has been received and saved to \"{localFileName}\"\r\n";
    }

    return MessageFactory.Text(replyText);
}
```

Here is the transcript of the conversation:
[image: Transcript bot framework]

EDIT:
i have edited my code to this , it still doesnt wait for me to upload a attachment .just finishes the step .

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DescStepAsync2(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    stepContext.Values["Desc"] = (string)stepContext.Result;
    var reply = (Activity)ProcessInput(stepContext.Context);
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(AttachmentPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = reply }, cancellationToken);
}
```

process input function :

```
private static IMessageActivity ProcessInput(ITurnContext turnContext)
{
    var activity = turnContext.Activity;
    IMessageActivity reply = null;

    if (activity.Attachments != null && activity.Attachments.Any())
    {
        // We know the user is sending an attachment as there is at least one item .
        // in the Attachments list.
        reply = HandleIncomingAttachment(activity);
    }
    else
    {
        reply = MessageFactory.Text("No attachement detected ");
        // Send at attachment to the user.              
    }
    return reply;
}
```

Comment: Is this the same as this issue? https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1799

Comment: not really , there its a sample request .

Comment: edited my original question*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so i figured this out , thanks to this post: github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5312

how my code looks now :

declaring a attachment prompt:

```
 public class CancelDialog : ComponentDialog
{

    private static string attachmentPromptId = $"{nameof(CancelDialog)}_attachmentPrompt";
    public CancelDialog()
        : base(nameof(CancelDialog))
    {

        // This array defines how the Waterfall will execute.
        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            TitleStepAsync,
            DescStepAsync,
          //  AskForAttachmentStepAsync,
            UploadAttachmentAsync,
            UploadCodeAsync,
            SummaryStepAsync,

        };

        // Add named dialogs to the DialogSet. These names are saved in the dialog state.
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
        AddDialog(new NumberPrompt<int>(nameof(NumberPrompt<int>), AgePromptValidatorAsync));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
        AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
        AddDialog(new AttachmentPrompt(attachmentPromptId));
```

ask for attachment prompt in the waterfall :

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> UploadAttachmentAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        stepContext.Values["desc"] = (string)stepContext.Result;
     //   if ((bool)stepContext.Result)
        {
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
        attachmentPromptId,
        new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Can you upload a file?"),
        });
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    return await stepContext.NextAsync(-1, cancellationToken);
        //}

    }
```

processing the file and storing it :

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> UploadCodeAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        List<Attachment> attachments = (List<Attachment>)stepContext.Result;
        string replyText = string.Empty;
        foreach (var file in attachments)
        {
            // Determine where the file is hosted.
            var remoteFileUrl = file.ContentUrl;

            // Save the attachment to the system temp directory.
            var localFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), file.Name);

            // Download the actual attachment
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, localFileName);
            }

            replyText += $"Attachment \"{file.Name}\"" +
                         $" has been received and saved to \"{localFileName}\"\r\n";
        }}
```

hope you get a idea .
thank you @Kyle and @Michael

Comment: It's great that you were able to solve your issue, but next time please consider accepting someone else's answer so they get reputation in return for the work they did for you

Comment: New to Stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

A [`WaterfallStepContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.waterfallstepcontext) inherits from `DialogContext` and therefore the `ITurnContext` can be accessed through its [`Context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.context) property. The waterfall step code you posted already does this when it uses `stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync` or `stepContext.Context.Activity`.

Comment: but the problem i am having is , as you can see in the transcript i have linked at the end is the dialog doesnt wait for me to upload

Comment: @SamitShirsat - If you mean to ask something different from the question I answered, then you should edit the title as well

Comment: let me do that , timezone difference between Bengaluru and yours is so unbfortunate . Im stuck on this issue since 3 days now .

Comment: I have done the same , please help . Tuesday got to show my team a prototype for a bot that raises a JIRA ticket . ticket thing is done , but this attachment thing has had me stuck for a while .

Comment: Got my answer though this : https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5312

but cant figure out , how to read the and store data from the var attachment.

Comment: i got the answer , i will post it tomorrow when im back in office .